# I have some problems to make react-native work on a physical device with expo app

Tags: react-native

[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDoFv.jpg)

I'm using MacBook Air M1.

To make react-native work on a physical device with expo application, I wrote these codes:

1. `npm install -g expo-cli`
2. `npx expo-cli init cars`
3. `cd cars`
4. `npm start`

But it doesn't work, I'm looking forward your replies thank you.

Comment: Hi Cihan, can you try expo start and if u are using android press a if its ios press i on your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to run expo start and make sure that port 8081 not used by any other server. Because in given screenshot it looks your port 8081 is already been used and on top of that you trying to run expo project thats why always failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your previous process is still running, try to stop those process and then start expo server again

Do this to stop the process:

- Run this command for getting PID of the process running in your port 8081

  lsof -i tcp:8081
- Note the PID from the table which is shown after that command
- Run this command to kill your process kill -9 {PID}.

  kill -9 3421

You have to add your PID in place of 3421 that I used.

I Hope that it helps..

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, ı applied the process but expo's localhost page doesn't start

Comment: Make sure that there isn't any firewall protection or antivirus turned on. Maybe this would be causing an issue